# How can I call code at run-time from a Rail initializer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, raygun

I am using Raygun for error tracking in an app which uses a sharded database. Separate clients store their data on their own shard of the DB server.

```
rails c
1> MultiSite.get_shard
#=> master
2> Post.count
#=> 0
3> MultiSite.set_shard :client1_prod
#=> nil
4> MultiSite.get_shard
#=> client1_prod
5> Post.count
#=> 123
```

When using Raygun, I can set error tags by using the Raygun `config/initializers/raygun.rb`:

```
Raygun.setup do |config|
  config.api_key = LOCAL_SETTINGS["raygun_token"]
  config.filter_parameters = Rails.application.config.filter_parameters
  config.version = EnvironmentInformation.get_version
  config.tags = [
                  EnvironmentInformation.get_server_name,
                  EnvironmentInformation.get_version,
                  EnvironmentInformation.get_commit_hash,
                  EnvironmentInformation.shard_name
                ]
  config.enable_reporting = true
end
```

So here I am trying to use `EnvironmentInformation.shard_name` to tell me which client (which shard) is experiencing the error so that I can filter on that tag on the Raygun app.

Unfortunately, on app startup (when the code in this initializer is run), we are still on the `master` shard. This means that Raygun tags every error as the `master` shard.

Is there any way I can amend my initializer so that I can call `EnvironmentInformation.shard_name` when an error actually occurs?

Googling around hasn't come up with anything yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Via feature request, the guys at Raygun have implemented a proc which can be used to dynamically set tags at runtime.

Although still of general interest, my specific problem has now been solved.

https://raygun.com/thinktank/suggestion/94060